# How to make a function that detects a character in a string and returns it's position in the string? Python 3.2

Tags: python, string, function, character, detect

I'm taking a programming course and the final is tomorrow.  I'm taking a practice final and I'm stuck on this question:

Given the following function heading

def firstOccur(ch, s):

Write a method that returns the first occurrence of the character stored in ch in the string s.  If the character is found in the string, your function should return it's position.  Thus if s = 'abcdefg' and the value of ch is 'd', your program would return 3.  If the character is not found in the string, your program should return -1.

I gave it a try, but no luck.  This is where I'm at:

```
def firstOccur(ch, s):
    b = len(s)
    n = 0
    for c in range(b):
        d = ch[0]
        e = s[c]
        if d != e:
            return(-1)
        else:
            while d != e:
                n = n+1
            return(n)
def main():
    a = firstOccur('d', 'abcdefg')
    print(a)
main()
```

The main function is just to test the firstOccur function.  I have no idea where to go from here, or if I'm even on the right path.  Help?

Comment: I presume that using the built in `string.find` function (which does exactly this) would not count as doing the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down. You're given a list of characters, aka a string. So the task is to iterate (=loop) over this list until you hit the first occurance of your search key within the list. Once you hit the occurance, return the position of it, which also breaks the loop. If you finish the loop without finding the search key, return `-1` (BTW; `None` would make more sense in Python).

Python offers you a builtin function called `enumerate` that takes a list and returns a list of tuples with element index and the element itself. i.e.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or
     "abcd"

becomes

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

This is a nobrainer.

```
def firstOccur(key, string):
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if key == c:
            return i
    return -1
```

If you're not allowed to use enumerate, well there's the "long" road as well:

```
def firstOccur(key, string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if key == string[i]:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: Yeah, can't use enumerate, but the last one was just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as the string.find() method :)
Anticipating that you're not allowed to use any more than the Python basics to solve this question...

```
for x in range(len(s)):
    if ch == s[x]:
        return x
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this; it will return the position with a zero index (ie, 0 for the first character, 1 for the second etc). Enumerate is able to track the current position for you.

```
def firstOccur(ch,s):
    for pos, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == ch:
            return pos

    return -1

a = firstOccur('d', 'abcdefg')
// a = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over a string like this in Python: `for c in range(b)`. You can simply grab each character from a string: `for character in s` loops over the string, giving you each character in turn.

`if d != e: return(-1)` - every time you hit a character that isn't what you want, you'll return. Also, if `ch` is a character, you don't need a `ch[0]`.

Python comes with a really handy function called `enumerate`. This will list the values in an `iterable` as well as their position. Here's an outline of how it could look:

```
for index, character in enumerate(s):
    if #<test condition here on character>:
        return index
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler way to do it would be to

```
def first_occur(my_string,my_char):
   try:
       return my_string.index(my_char)
   except ValueError:
       return -1
```

If you are not allowed to use any methods of types (I hope I said that correctly) or built-ins like range

```
def first_occur(my_string,my_char):
    count=0:
    for value in my_string:

        if value==my_char:
            return count
        count+=1

   return -1
```

I would think that if you can't use enumerate you should not be able to use range

If you move the count+=1 to the line after for value then the list will be indexed at 1, otherwise it is indexed at zero